# JS statements in haml templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, templates, haml, ejs

I use ror3 + backbone.js and ejs + haml + haml_assets for templating. I need to use if/else statement in template. In jst.ejs template i can:

```
<% if(address != '') {%>
   <li><%= address %></li>
<% } %>
```

But in jst.ejs.haml it not work. How can i use js statements in haml templating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but it looks like you can use [haml.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/haml.js/) to achieve this.

That way, your particular code snippet would look like this:

```
- if(address !== '')
  %li= address
```

Haml has a way of doing weird things with some parts of the languages it uses (removing {} here, obviously), though, so the above doesn't really look much like javascript any longer...